# pcb-4-pin passive crystal is soldered to a 2-pin crystal PCB package

Tags: pcb, crystal, footprint

I would like to know whether it is suitable (not harmful) to put a 4 pin passive crystal in a 2 pin footprint.

Thanks in advance.

I have a 2 pin footprint in my PCB board,however,I only have a 4 pin passive crystal (8M). I have to solder like this: connect 1# to 2#,connect 3# to 4#;[image]
[image]

Comment: can you put more details, are you designing or changing a crystal? what models?

Comment: It's often possible to build such a "3d sculpture" on a prototype but it will likely be fragile, may radiate more, and in extreme cases might not work.  You may also need to consider if the leading caps are right.

Answer (score 1):

You should connect both end of crystal at their place and GND of 4-pin crystal to GND on your PCB. GND on crystal is for shielding and if you don't connect it it will work but radiate more.